# Cannot POST form NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, forms, express, post, ejs

I have a form which dynamically adds user data from the user into a table.
[This is the final form look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1w6O.png)

When one of these **Use this account** is pressed it shows, `Cannot POST /like`.

This is the form. I use`EJS`.

```
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
              <div class = "form-group col-sm-12">
                <label for="tagsarray">Enter Tags</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="likes" name="likes" aria-placeholder="Enter tags seperated by a comma">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-7">
                  <label for="numberoftimes">Enter Number of Actions</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="action" name="action" aria-placeholder="Enter No. of Actions">
                </div>
                <% if (accounts) {%>
                  <table class = "striped">
                    <tbody>
                      <% accounts.forEach(accounts => { %>
                        <tr>
                          <td><a href="<% accounts._id %>"></a><%= accounts.title%></td>
                          <td><a href= "/like/<%= accounts._id%>"><button type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary col-auto" >Use this account</button></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tr>
                      <%});%>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                <%} else {%>
                  <p>You have no accounts added</p>
                <% } %>
            </form>
```

This is my `controller.js`

```
control.get('/like', async(req, res) => {
    try{
        const accounts = await account.find({user: req.user.id}).lean()
        res.render("backend/like", {
            name: req.user.name,
            accounts
        });
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    
});

control.post('/like/:id', getuserdata, (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        let title = res.accountuser.title;
        let pass = res.accountuser.password;
        let tags = req.body.likes;
        let actions = req.body.action;
        console.log(title, pass, tags, actions)
        iglike(title, pass, tags, actions)
        next();
        res.redirect('/like')
    }catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

This does not catch any error and the console shows absolutely nothing. The only error is `Cannot POST /like`.

This is the `getuserdata` function for reference

```
async function getuserdata(req, res, next) {
    let accountuser
    try{
        accountuser = await account.findById(req.params.id)
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

    res.accountuser = accountuser
    next()
};
```

I have tried with a simple `type=submit` button with no `href` still shows the same error

Please help me solve this `Cannot POST /like` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a default action for your form, to make the route to work with post. If you use `href` it does a get by default.

To make a post in your route, you should remove the href and put an default action in your form.

```
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off"  action="/like/<%= accounts._id%>">
```

Then in the line your have the submit button, remove the `href` (as it was moved to default action from form)

```
<td><button type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary col-auto" >Use this account</button></a></td>
```

Comment: This works, but is also makes my form loop and the accounts._id fetches the 1st account only. Can you please help me with the loop?

Comment: Well, the easy way is to do a foreach, for each item in the form. You will have to  put the `<% accounts.forEach(accounts => { %>` outside the html `form` tag.

Comment: Another way is intercept the submit with javascript and do a ajax (using fetch api, jquery or axios) POST call to your backend.

Comment: On doing it ```<% accounts.forEach(accounts => { %>``` outside the form tag, it also loops the form elements, like the text boxes and they display twice.

Answer (score 0):

/like is a GET request

for POST request you need to use
/like/1
where 1 can be any parameter

Comment: Isn't /like/:id a parameter?

Comment: parameter was not passed that's why it is showing error

Comment: I understand, I think, in place of control.post('/like/:id'), I should put something like /like/post or something?

Comment: yes in /like/post where post is id here then req.params.id will be equal to "post"